# Email ID for the same email changes?

Tags: gmail, gmail-api

I'm facing an issue lately that the id of an email changes.

I have an application that search the mail box on an hourly basis and I store the email id in order to prevent processing of the same email twice (the scans overlap hence I see the same emails more than once).

Any idea what can cause this change?

Comment: Can you post the code you are using? And if there is an error message that you receive when doing this activity.

Comment: I'm using http://www.rubydoc.info/github/google/google-api-ruby-client/Google%2FApis%2FGmailV1%2FGmailService%3Alist_user_messages  and I store the id field of each message. A few hours later I do the same and the id of the same message changes. http://www.rubydoc.info/github/google/google-api-ruby-client/Google/Apis/GmailV1/Message

Comment: @KENdi it seems that the two identical emails share the same internal_date. The problem is , I don't know if that's unique. I can try checking if the same internal_date exists and than compare the HTML content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand you mean Google's ID which is returned by the API like with this example code; https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/list#try-it

That ID of a message doesn't change by itself.

If one moves the email out of the account, and back in (via IMAP), then it would get a new ID.

Also, if you check the same email but in a different Gmail account, the ID will be different. the ID is unique only per account.

Perhaps it is useful for you to use the message-id? The message-id uniquely identifies any email, this ID is in the email header generated by the sending server and does not change. You can search for it in Gmail with rfc822msgid:

Hope this answers your question, but also let us know if not. ^^

Comment: Using Class: Google::Apis::GmailV1::Message , I should check header "X-Original-MessageID" , it looks like this "<urn.rtn.msg.20161125222312f27de83d134b488b8f7309ada4a0p0na@1480112593980.rtn-svc-na-1a-94488c18.us-east-1.amazon.com>"  I'm seeing a few other similar signatures. But I guess I should stick to this one , right?